# Access VBA loop and show offset record data

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am writing a vba code that loops through records and if record equals environment username then display its offset records of found username within a form showing in labels.

So far I have come across a brick wall, trying to get the values that belong to the matching username.

[image: Table]

### [image: Access Form]

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM agentKPI")

    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            'Perform an edit
         rs.Edit
         rs("staffName") = Environ$("username")

            Form!agentKPI!label10.Caption
            Form!agentKPI!label14.Caption
            Form!agentKPI!label23.Caption
            Form!agentKPI!label26.Caption

            'rs!kpi1 = True
            'rs("kpi1") = True 'The other way to refer to a field

            'Save contact name into a variable
            'sContactName = rs!staffName & " " & rs!staffID
            'rs!kpi3 = sContactName
            rs.Update
            'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
    End If

    MsgBox ("Finished looping through records." & Environ$("username"))

    rs.Close 'Close the recordset
    Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Comment: can it be more than one record in table for each `Environ$("username")`?

Comment: the aim will be to show kpi results for whoever is logged in. So it will be one record found

Comment: you have only 3 kpi: `kpi1`,`kpi2`,`kpi3`, but 4 labels. What should be in 4th label? and also what is `agentKPI`, form or subform?

Comment: agentkpi is a access form, the forth label will be to show agent name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it will be one record found

use this code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlStr As String

sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM agentKPI WHERE staffName = '" & Environ$("username") & "'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    Forms!agentKPI!Label10.Caption = rs("staffName")
    Forms!agentKPI!Label14.Caption = rs("kpi1")
    Forms!agentKPI!Label23.Caption = rs("kpi2")
    Forms!agentKPI!Label26.Caption = rs("kpi3")
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

MsgBox "Finished looping through records. " & Environ$("username")

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Comment: i run the code and a error message appears invalid use of me!

Comment: where do you place the code? in _form_ module or in _standart_ module? try my updated code

Comment: i have created an external macro called module1 and i have generated a procedure for the command4 "show results button" in this I have placed the macro name getkpidetails

Comment: have you tried my updated code with `Forms!agentKPI!` instead `Me!`?

Comment: thanks for that @simoco, the code started to work after afew seconds, I quickly google to find the same answer. https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fp2p.wrox.com%2Faccess-vba%2F34253-what-does-me-dim-stand-vba-coding.html&ei=ezJBU77sMYLm7Aay64GwAw&usg=AFQjCNGlB20gFCCFDkc6fdKnSTxSCAEllw&sig2=VjuITxkDmMBgUdwnQNJDRg

Comment: the code you written above is this a slicker method of writing the code? Because it gives another error "object doesnt support this property or method"

Comment: I've ralled back my edit and swithed to previous code, but just for curious in what line of code it gives you an error?

Comment: the errror it provided was "object doesnt support this property or method" I have gone back to the previous code version and this is now showing an error "Microsoft Access cannot find the referenced form 'agentKPI' "

Comment: oh okay then the form name is the same but i'll change it to something else and change it back. See if that works

Comment: Really do not do this `Environ$("username")` it is open to SQL injection and the way it is stated above will not cope with user names that have apostrophes. There are better ways to get a user name in VBA.